# iptables FORWARD rule

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I'm running 3 virtual machines with Fedora 19. The machine B is set up with two networks adapters and provides que channel between machine A and machine C.

The machine A IP is set to `192.168.1.1` and machine C IP is set to `172.16.1.1`. On machine B I have one adapter with IP `192.168.1.254` and another adapter with IP `172.16.1.254`.

I've created this rule in machine B (it's working as a router):

> iptables -P INPUT DROP
>
> iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

And so, no connections between the machines are made unless the `PING` that allows the communication between  machine A and B.

Now I want to create a rule in the router that allows the communication of `HTTPS` between the external network (machine C) and the internal network (machine A)

I've added this rule in machine B:

> iptables -A FORWARD -o p7p1 -p tcp --dport 443 -d 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT

Where `p7p1` is the interface on machine B that connects to machine A.
I've also tried:

> iptables -A FORWARD -i p8p1 -o p7p1 -p tcp --dport 443 -d 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT

Where `p8p1` is the interface on machine B that connects to machine C.

Now, on machine A I do `nc -l 443` and on machine C `nc 192.168.1.1 443` but I'm getting `Ncat: Connection timed out`

Whats wrong with my rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a rule that also allows the answers to go through your firewall.

I trust the code for netfilter and its powerful `state` module, so i'd use `iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` so that also the packets in the other direction are allowed as well.

In your ruleset the answers from 192.168.1.1 to the other machine at 172.16.1.1 are blocked.

Also see documentation for iptables troubleshooting, for example [this on linuxhomenetworking.com](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch14_:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables#Troubleshooting_iptables) and add logging rules when things are not working.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```